# Uniqueness-like constraint but with limit greater than 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a bookings table where I currently have a unique constraint which prevents multiple bookings having the same start/end time.

```
mysql> desc booking;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| customer_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_time  | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_time    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show indexes from booking;
+---------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| booking |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | id          | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| booking |          0 | uniq_booking_idx     |            1 | start_time  | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| booking |          0 | uniq_booking_idx     |            2 | end_time    | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

However, now our business constraint has changed and we want to be able to allow ***up to five*** bookings at the same time.

What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Answer (score 0):

Not all things can be easily achieved in SQL.  I think the best approach is to do the test in the application.  In pseudo code:

```
START TRANSACTION;
$ct = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking WHERE ...
if ($ct >= 5)
    error to user
else
    INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

OK, I guess this could be encapsulated in a Stored Procedure, plus error handling in your application.